# Is Mass Transfer Account functionality exposed in Apex

Tags: apex

Transferring Accounts via the '[Mass Transfer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_transfer.htm&type=5)' UI also automatically transfers Contacts with the same owner, and presents some additional options,

> When you change record ownership, some
>   associated items that are owned by the current record owner are also
>   transferred to the new owner.
>
> > Contacts (on business accounts only), attachments, notes, open
> >     activities, open opportunities owned by the current account owner, and
> >     optionally, closed opportunities and open opportunities owned by other
> >     users.

Is this functionality exposed in Apex or via other APIs?  I was unable to find it.

I ran a simple test and simply updating Account Owner ID via Apex does not transfer the related contact.  I am looking to automate post-deactivation processes for users, and account transfer is the main sticky wicket.  The rest is already handled via flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an API for that, and I don't see an [Idea](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) that specifically addresses this need. As a workaround, you could probably write a Process Builder to force ownership change for all contacts owned by the previous account owner, or do so in Apex Code directly.